# Declare property as one of the values in an array

Tags: typescript

I am writing some types that will be serialized. I need to be 100% sure that a property is "one of the allowed values".

```
export const operationTypes = ["a", "b"]

export type Operation = {
    type: string in operationTypes // <-- this should demonstrate what I am trying to do
}

// Use this when parsing to be 100% sure that operation type is a valid string
function validateOperationType(operation: Operation) {
    return operationTypes.includes(operation.type)
}
```

In other words. The "type" property in Operation must be one of the values in an array. And I must be able to verify that this value actually exists in the array (at runtime).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) on your `operationTypes` variable, and define the `type` property as `typeof operationTypes[number]`:

```
export const operationTypes = ["a", "b"] as const;

export type Operation = {
    type: typeof operationTypes[number];
}

function validateOperationType(operation: Operation) {
    return operationTypes.includes(operation.type);
}

const operation1: Operation = { type: 'a' }; // OK
const operation2: Operation = { type: 'c' }; // Error
```